# Sql script - Select multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure to select multiple tables from a database

Lets assume that i want to select three tables . I want the result to look like this :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: so whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL like that:

```
SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE_2
UNION ALL
SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE_3;
```

Remember that selected values must have the same aliases within all tables.